Frequency of Oscillators
Greetings to the community,
Recently I have been tinkering with FM transmitters/receivers, and as such have become familiar with many different oscillatory circuits. One thing that stood out to me is that the frequency was usually controlled by an inductor and a capacitor, with a mathematical relation of the form, 1/LC or 1/sqrt{LC}. My question boils down to, is there a theoretical or practical maximum to the power the LC product can take e.g. 1/LC^{100}? Is there like a recipe to cook up circuits with arbitrary powers in the LC denominator? Can you provide examples?


One thing that stood out to me is that the frequency was usually controlled by an inductor and a capacitor, with a mathematical relation of the form, 1/LC

No, that doesn't have the dimensions for frequency. If you've seen it somewhere, the source is wrong.

... or 1/sqrt{LC}.

Yes, that has the right dimensions, 1/s.

My question boils down to, is there a theoretical or practical maximum to the power the LC product can take e.g. 1/LC^{100}? Is there like a recipe to cook up circuits with arbitrary powers in the LC denominator?

No, the only power that works to get frequency from the LC product is 0.5.
